# Querying field in all documents and identifying which document the field is found in?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase's Firestore and am trying to complete a query and return a result.

My db structure consists of:

[Collection]"users"

[Document]"userID"(unique hash)

[Fields]"WalletAddress"

I am trying to create a query that will search through the walletAddress Fields of all userID Documents and if it finds the walletAddress, returns the userID it found it in.

I am having difficulty figuring out how to create the reference for all Documents in the collection.

Working in Java.

Thank you for nay and all help.

Comment: Querying Firestore is pretty well documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries. What you need seems to be a condition on `WalletAddress`, so something along the lines of `Firestore.getInstance().collection("users").whereEqualTo("WalletAddress", "ValueYouAreLookingFor")`. If you're having a hard time making that work, it's probably a lot easier to help if you edit the question to show what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  Just trying to wrap my head around this.  Will that above code search through all documents in the "users" collection for the field "walletAddress"?  Or will it search through "users" collection for document called "walletAddress"?  Do I not have to specify the document I want to search through?

Comment: It searches all documents in the `users` collection for ones that have a field `WalletAddress` equal to `"ValueYouAreLookingFor"`. I'd highly recommend reading the documentation I linked too, as that should explain it much better than I can do in a few comments here.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm reading through it again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CollectionReference walletAddrs =  fStore.collection("users");

Query queryAddr1 = walletAddrs.whereEqualTo("walletAddress1", queryAddr);

queryAddr1.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document:task.getResult()){

                    userID = document.getId();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```